# ASP.NET Razor Pages loading huge amount of data, better performance?

Tags: asp.net, database, razor-pages

I am working on a project for school and i have about 1700 Ingredients in my SQL.Database. When i want to load the Ingredients page it is loading 10  seconds, after 10 seconds i can see the data and after another 3 seconds the data is loaded correct with DataTabels.net JQuery. Is there a way to load the data from my SQL Database by the time? So that i can see 100 Ingredients instandly and the other ones are loaded while i am on the page?

This is how i load the data with my repository

```
private readonly IIngredientsRepository _ingredientsRepository;
    public IndexModel(IIngredientsRepository ingredientsRepository)
    {
        _ingredientsRepository = ingredientsRepository;
    }    
    public IList<TIngredient> TIngredients { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
            TIngredients = await _ingredientsRepository.GetAllAsync().ToListAsync();
    }
```

**Repository implementation:**
My IIngredientsRepository is implementing following Repository

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, new()
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            return _db.Set<TEntity>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Couldn't retrieve entities: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

I am **displaying the Data** on the razor page with the following code:

```
 <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-hover text-center table-sm table-bordered">
        @*Tabellen Kopf*@
        <thead>
            <tr class="stylish-color-dark text-white">
                <th class="font-weight-bold TableHeadFontSize">
                    Bezeichnung
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @*Tabellen Daten*@
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.TIngredients)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="TableBodyFontSize text-left pl-3">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:200px;">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <a class="btn red lighten-1 text-white btn-sm" asp-page="Delete" asp-route-Id="@item.Id" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Löschen">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Script for dataTable**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable({
            "searching": false,
            "pageLength": 25,
            "language": {
                "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json"
            }
        });
        $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Or should i implement a paging where i only load data per page?

Comment: depending on what you are using the table for you could try TIngredients = await _ingredientsRepository.GetAllAsync().AsNoTracking().ToListAsync(); to get a bit of a speed bump